# Keyboard shortcuts not working when MSWord is open since Anniversary Upgrade

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-word, keyboard-shortcuts

This turns out to be very hard to Google, for reasons that will become clear:

I am using Windows 10.  I have several keyboard shortcuts that open various programs.  For example <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>M</kbd> opens a command window, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>N</kbd> opens a browser, etc.  These keyboard shortcuts are defined via the properties menus attached to various shortcuts that point to these programs.

I have spent the past week recovering from havoc wrought  by the Anniversary Upgrade, and am down to one thing I can't seem to fix. Since the upgrade, whenever Microsoft Word is open, the above-mentioned keyboard shortcuts do not work.  The instant I close Word, they start working again.

It occurred to me that this might be because Word has its own default assignments for key combinations like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>M</kbd>.  So I deleted all of those within-Word keyboard shortcuts, but this did not help.

I find this impossible to Google for, because whenever you put the phrases "keyboard shortcut" and "microsoft word" in the same Google search, you get only hits that concern the use of keyboard shortcuts **in** Microsoft Word, not other keyboard shortcuts that are **affected** by Microsoft word.

I've become very reliant on these shortcuts, and (unlike in normal times) am currently working on a project that makes me want Word open all the time.  So I'd really like this fixed.

I'll be glad for suggestions.

**Update:**  This just got weirder.  When I open MSWord from a command window (as is my wont), the problem occurs.  But when I open the exact same `.exe` file by clicking on it in File Explorer, the problem does not occur.  I have verified this through multiple openings and closings of the program.  And I have verified that it it really is the same version of Word opening each time:  Microsoft Professional Plus 2010 build 14.0.7122.5000.

This is a partial fix to my problem, as it means that I can avoid the issue by training myself to open with File Explorer instead of from a command window.  I'd still prefer to really solve it though.

Comment: Does it matter if word has focus as opposed to another program?

Comment: Could you post the exact command you use to open word in the terminal?

Comment: @birdman3131:  It does not matter whether Word has focus.  It only matters whether it's open.

Comment: @Carrein:  The exact command is "winword" or "winword [filename]".

Comment: How about launching word through the shortcut instead (by terminal)?

Comment: Ctrl-Alt-M and Ctrl-Alt-N are not defined as Keyboard Shortcuts in Word 2019. Are they defined in word 2019? for what? As you said you deleted their assignment in 2010.

Comment: I had got w10 updated to 1803 and then to 1809 and no keyboard shortcut problem had appeared with my Word 2016, and later when 1809 was working, no problem when I installed Word 2019 also. Of course, I didn't have these two or any shortcuts defined. Try changing these shortcuts to something else, say, to Ctrl-Alt-K or anything that is not defined anywhere, just to test whether some changes in the shortcut makes the new shortcut work, or no kind of shortcut will work.